# How do i access the array from Layout to Controller in Zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

Say for example in mydefaultlayout.phtml i have an array declared in this way

```
$pages['words'] = array( 'APPLE', 'BALL', 'CAT', 'DOG', 'HELL', 'INK', 'PINK');
$pages['letters'] = array( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'H', 'I', 'K');
```

Mydefaultlayout.phtml has been my default layout in the entire application so it is available to every controller. So How do I access this elements `$pages['words']` and `$pages['letters']` in my controller.

How can i assign them to the view from the controller.

```
Class MyController extends Zend_controller_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
        if($_POST['page']=='ABC'){
            //How do i assign this $pages['words']  and $pages['letters']  to the view  
            $view->myarray = $pages['words'];
            $view->myarray = $pages['letters']; 
        }
    } 
}
```

One solution i have in mind is again redefine the `$pages['words']`  and `$pages['letters']` in the  controller and assign it to the view 
which is the repeatative code. How can i access the `$pages['words']`  and `$pages['letters']` in the controller or view directly

Comment: just define the letters in the controller and assign it to the view? o.O

Comment: And if you need it in only some controllers, then an [controller action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) can be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't access any view variable from controller.

better to define data $page['words'] and $page['latters'] at model, and access it when you need it from both controller and view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little off the cuff, but why is the array defined in your layout?

If you need to have it available everywhere why not define it say in your bootstrap & then pass it to the views/controllers as and when you need?

So in your bootstrap you can have something like this:

```
$pages['words'] = array( 'APPLE', 'BALL', 'CAT', 'DOG', 'HELL', 'INK', 'PINK'); 

$pages['letters'] = array( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'H', 'I', 'K');

$view->pages = $pages;
```

Then in your views, you can access them:

```
print_r($this->pages);
```

Hope this is helpful, just going from memory & in a rush :)

Answer (score 0):

in your controller

```
public function indexAction(){
    $this->view->myarray = array('a','b','c','d');
}
```

in your layout

```
<?
foreach($this->myarray  as $key => $value ){
    echo " $key => $value  <br>";
}
?>
```